# Transfer Google Search Console Ownership

Tags: google-search-console

I am going to start a website re-design project.

The previous web designer has used his personal email address instead of the client email address to add the website to Google Search Console.

Should I delete the Google verification file associated with GSA from the old project and create a new account with the client email address or is there a way to transfer the ownership of the existing account to my client account?

Comment: If you have the previous web designer's cooperation, or can access the property as an owner, you can use the [verification delegation feature](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/03/sharing-verification-love.html) to add a new verified owner. If you don't have either, you'll need to setup a new property and re-verity the site again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ownership, you have to verify using the general HTML tag or any other verification procedures. There is no other way around.

If you're trying to grant/revoke permissions from other users (who are not owners), you can do it by clicking on the Settings -> Users & Permissions option in the Google Search Console.